# can the user delete the NSUserDefaults setting, like android's sharedPreferences?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Is a simple question but I only found that you can delete the NSUserDefaults settings via code.

I need to know if the user can delete the NSUserDefaults settings like in Android you can go to the app's configurations and delete the app's data.

Thanks : )!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an end-user flow, deleting the app or going into Settings > General > Reset All Settings effectively deletes any locally saved data for an iOS app, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to know if the user can delete the NSUserDefaults settings like in Android you can go to the app's configurations and delete the app's data.

Yes, the user can easily do this - by deleting the app from the device. (The user holds down the Home button until the app icons in the springboard "jiggle", and then taps the "X" at the corner of an app icon.) This removes the app's sandbox, and the NSUserDefaults is a file in the sandbox and is destroyed along with everything else.

If the user then reinstalls the app, it gets a fresh start - as far as the NSUserDefaults is concerned.

(Other, system-level "memories" about this app are not necessarily forgotten merely because the user deletes the app.)

Comment: well of course xD if you delete the app all the data of that app its gone but I meant like in android that you can only delete de shared preferences data. In iOS is the same? I ask because I look in the configurations menu and in my app I don't see any way to delete the data of that app.

Comment: Do not say "of course". You asked a question because presumably you did not know the answer. I think I told you the answer. I know nothing about Android but I do know what happens in iOS and I'm telling you what it is. The way that I have stated is the way the user can do it.

Comment: Sorry I really don't want to be rude, I understand your answer and I appreciated , but like my question ask, I want to know the differences with android's shared preferences

Comment: No problem. My point is just that it was not clear from your question what you already knew and what you wanted to know. So there is no need to dismiss my answer; it is true and it is trying to be helpful.